# play animation regardless of any screen iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have some animation to be played at some point in time. that time is decided by some thread running in the backgroud. now i want to play the animation regardless of which screen the user is on. here is screen hierarchy.

login-->homescreen(thread starts running from viewdidload).

from home screen the user may navigate to any other screen and i want the animation to be played. right now i have the animationviewcontrller a membervariable in the homescreen and i am calling it by allocing and initing and pushing and popping when animation is done. and it works only 10% of the time. i have tried performselectoronmainthread and its still the same.

How do i redesign my code such that is plays on anyscreen.

here is my code for my thread.

```
[self startTimerThread];   // in viewdidload

-(void)startTimerThread
{
    homescreenthread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setupTimerThread) object:nil];
    [homescreenthread start];
}
-(void)setupTimerThread
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(findnewmessages)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    //[runLoop addTimer:timer forModes:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [runLoop run];
    [pool release];
}

-(void)findnewmessages
{//finding message from server here. i am using the following request
    NSData *serverReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *replyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[serverReply bytes] length:[serverReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

//i have omitted lot of other code.
    }

Comment: Explain more about why you start a thread from the homescreen and what is being done on that thread that requires an animation to be played on the main thread.

Comment: i have a thread because it constantly keeps polling the server to check if the any messages in the background. if it finds any message it inserts the message into the database(sqlite) and should let the users now of it with an animation.

Comment: Have you considered using a timer (and therefore the runloop instead of a thread) to perform the polling at the desired interval and then using asynchronous `NSURLConnection`s? This would eliminate the thread and any possibility of it adversely affecting your animation.

Comment: @Jasarien i have edited my post , please have a look at it.

Comment: Why on earth do you spawn a whole new thread just to run a timer? Timers can run on the main thread and not block it. And use `NSURLConnection`'s ***a*synchronous** methods.

Comment: @Jasarien so you are saying, if i use a timeR on the main thread and also use NSURLConnection's *a*synchronous it will not interrupt the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the delegate of the app to display the animation view.

```
id appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.m_window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Also if you are tying to draw anything on the screen it should be done on main thread.

Please let me know if it helps.